# Backward compatibity using v-21/styles.xml not working

Tags: android, xml, backwards-compatibility

I am trying to style my button while maintaining backwards compatibility.

I have 2 files as follows:

`values/styles.xml:`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RoundedButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RoundedButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    </style>

    <style name="AppName.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DemoButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">40dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`values-v21/styles.xml:`

```
<resources>
    <style name="RoundedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_rounded</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But even then my button looses all attributes i.e. just a text is displayed as per android-studio's "XML preview". I just want the button to default to the usual Holo theme on pre-lolipop devices. It works as expected on Lolipop devices.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you apply the button style? Globally (buttonStyle) or in layout files?

Comment: @ThomasR. Globally. I didn't need to specify it in my buttons

Answer (score 0):

In values/styles.xml

```
<style name="RoundedButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
</style>
```

change it to as Follow :-

```
 <style name="RoundedButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo">
 </style>
```

Comment: ok 
have you try by removing  this following  line from values/styles.xml in   "AppTheme" <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RoundedButton</item> and apply individual style to button.try tht it may work. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the reason of why this was happening so I removed the line `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RoundedButton</item>` from my `values/styles.xml` file, and added it to my `values-v21/styles.xml`.

I do not like this solution as there is a lot of code duplication. The only good thing about it is that it works.

Now my files look like:

`values/styles.xml:`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppName.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DemoButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">40dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`v21/styles.xml:`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RoundedButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RoundedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_rounded</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppName.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DemoButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">40dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```